# Image not showing in deployed vue.js app

Tags: image, web, build, vuejs2

I have created a vue.js app which works perfectly when run in localhost. when I build it and deploy to a website , the images don't display.

The images are in the src>assets folder.

I am using the ([progressive-image plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progressive-image)).

Is there anything I must do to ensure that the images are included in the build file?

Comment: Do you upload static images to server?

Comment: Ok so I thought that the webpack build included the assets folder (idiot that I am, I now know that it doesn't). I also suspected that the progressive-image plugin was causing the problems so I uninstalled it, I then uploaded the assets folder with the images to the server and displayed them using plain html. It is working fine. I may re-install the progressive-image plugin and try again...