# Images uploaded in Vue.js production mode not showing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am a bit new to Vue.js. I am doing a social media application that allows users to upload and share images with others. I store my images in src/assets folder during development. However, when I build the project, all images are put in the dist folder. Therefore, what can I do to enable users to still upload images on production? Do I create the assets directory in the dist folder? 
I have since tried different ways, including storing images on the backend. In dooing this, I reference the backend path relatively, using, for example, *../../../backend/public/assets...*, and it works on development. However, when I build, the images that existed in the backend directory at the time of building are visible, however, whenever I try uploading more on production to the *../../../backend/public/assets...* directory, they are uploaded successfully but are not visible (that is on production). I get an error that *Cannot find module './image_name.image_extension'*. 
What am I doing wrong?
I have seen similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051772/image-not-showing-in-deployed-vue-js-app) but there was no answer.

Comment: You shouldn't be uploading images to the same directory as your VueJS app, but to a separate, dedicated location on your server that is independent from your app.

Comment: Thank you @Terry. How should I ensure that they are visible on the production version of the application then? Where does the production version look for images from explicitly? Because it is currently giving a *Cannot find module* error upon uploading one on production.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your public path and change your way!!

first step to do is creating vue.config.js in your root directory, if you want to know more details, read this: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/

for example, I define prefix path for my files:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/" : "/",
};
```

remember, It's better if you use "@" to define your paths.
for example, if you want to load a image which located in src/assets/files/img/myImage.png, you can use @/assets/files/img/myImage.png in template section for binding or script section of your .vue files!
It always help you to find correct path of your files.

and finally your way is not standard because "src/assets/..." will used for compiled scripts and styles and also your files which you want to use on your UI layout like static images. so you have to use "public/assets/..." directory to save your file, then you will see everything is going well for you.

if you have a more question or stuck solving this problem again, I'm here to fix your issues.

Comment: As for the publicPath as described in the link you provided, it is *The base URL your application bundle will be deployed at*. Moreover, it says that *By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain*, which I feel like is the case with my application. However, I thought the point of concern here was the assetsDir? I had integrated an assetsDir in vue.config.js earlier to point to my backend static location as described here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1954 but I got this error *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'*

Comment: When you want vue manage your path of uploads, usually we have your same problems and as i mentioned before, you must set public/assets instead src/assets. Finally your back-end must access to your public directory and save your file (Then You have to upload vue in backend directory or set more configuration in vue.config.js like assetsDir), However if you want manage your path just with your end-point it's better, because then all of you need is a post request to your end-point and manage your file with NodeJs, PHP and etc via vue-axios in every directory which you choose it before.