How to properly import custom css and js files in Vue.js project
I have a paid admin dashboard template which in an HTML form, so I'm in the process of converting it to Vue.
How can I import the css and js properly in Vue?
Like jQuery, bootstrap bundles, perfect-scrollbar etc?
Is the only solution is put them in public folder and attach each manually in the index.html because when I tried to import them, they are considered as module.
This is my attempt. It works on npm run dev but once built and deploy the dist to server, it now errors because the links are still pointing to src
App.vue:
<script setup>
    import { onMounted } from 'vue'
    import { loadExternalScripts } from './utils/scriptLoader';

    onMounted(() => {
        const scripts = [
            '/src/assets/js/plugins/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
            '/src/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
            '/src/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js',
        ];

        loadExternalScripts(scripts)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('All external scripts loaded successfully');
                // Now you can safely use any jQuery or Bootstrap functions here
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error loading external scripts:', error);
            });
    });
</script>

<template>
    <router-view />
</template>

<style scoped></style>

scriptLoader.js
const loadedScripts = new Set();

export function loadExternalScripts(scripts) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const loadScript = (index) => {
            if (index >= scripts.length) {
                resolve(); // Resolve when all scripts are loaded
                return;
            }

            const src = scripts[index];
            if (loadedScripts.has(src)) {
                loadScript(index + 1); // Skip already loaded scripts
                return;
            }

            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            script.onload = () => {
                loadedScripts.add(src);
                loadScript(index + 1); // Load next script
            };
            script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Script load error: ${src}`));
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        };

        loadScript(0); // Start loading scripts from the first one
    });
}


Why not use a boilerplate? https://github.com/vuejs-templates or cli? https://cli.vuejs.org/

I'm currently studying Vuejs, came from backend laravel and just using blade templating.

Still though... Why not use a boilerplate? There's a lot of ways to answer your question, but one of the simlper ones is "just grab a boilerplate, use npm install them @import your scripts in the files where you need them". It's generally simpler to grab a standard boilerplate written by those who know what they're doing and learn in the context of their good examples.

that requires me to check each library the paid theme is using and npm install them each though. rather than just get it straight from the theme itself.

Have you reviewed the documentation for static asset loading in Vue? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html - You might want to reconsider using jQuery in Vue. Maybe check out: https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue - Also, what do you mean "check each library the paid theme"? Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169729/images-uploaded-in-vue-js-production-mode-not-showing
